# Python: FastAPI call that creates a task returns asynchronous result. How To?

Tags: python, asynchronous, task

I want to implement an app with an API, through FastAPI, that does the following:

Each API call creates a Task. This task is put in a queue by a Task Broker and pulled or pushed through on a message channel by/to distributed Workers. These workers process the task and obtain a result which they broadcast on the message channel. The Task Broker picks up this broadcast and thus the result and removes the task from the queue. The API call returns with the result thus picked up.

This mostly works. A task is created, the Task Broker adds the task to its queue, distributes it to a worker, obtains the result from the workers and removes it again. Only the last part I haven't gotten working: the API call returning a result.

Unsure how to implement it. I am using asyncio and would like some kind of callback.

A simplified impression of the code is as follows.

The API:

```
async def post_document(document: BaseDocument):
"""Create the document with a specific type and an optional name given in the payload"""
task = DocumentTask({
    'channel': 'worker',
    'document': document.dict(),
    'subtype': "POST_DOCUMENT"
})

result = await task_broker.give_task(task)
return result
```

The Task Broker

```
async def give_task(self, task_obj):
    self.add_task_to_queue(task_obj)
    self.message_channel.publish(task_obj)
```

And then asynchronously, the worker picks the task up, processes it, publishes a result task which the Task Broker picks up and after which the Task Broker removes the original task by a remove_task_from_queue method. 
But unsure on how to link that back to the API call.
Any help?